# Is it possible to create an own calendar system in cocoa touch / UIKit?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, nsdate, nscalendar

There are some constants for NSLocale, like NSJapaneseCalendar, but what if I wanted to create a "Physical Calendar" or something that isn't there? Is there a way to define an arbitrary calendar system and then use that with NSDate, NSDateComponents and NSCalendar?

Comment: I'd really like to know the answer to this myself.

Comment: Related question: [Creating a new NSCalendar calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334318/creating-a-new-nscalendar-calendar)

Answer (score 2):

In UIKit it's not possible because you can't define your own locale, that is what you need to create your custom calendar system using NSCalendar.

What you should do is define your custom locale and use it with the `initWithCalendarIdentifier` for create a really custom calendar.

With "define" I'm saying:

- create the necessary files on /usr/share/locale/
- edit the locale.gen file to add your locale
- execute the localgen program to compile your locale

Then you can create a custom calendar using the identifier you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Tapku library has a calendar view

http://tapku.com/

http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

you may be interested in this..

Answer (score 1):

check this Q&A, comprehensive listing of calendar API's:

[Is there any ready-made calendar control for iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Another git project, Kal can be found here: https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Works with both SQLite and JSON data sources